# Translate of a sql query into spark transformation

Tags: apache-spark, dataset, apache-spark-sql, apache-spark-dataset

I want to make my transformation on my data into my programme Spark-JAVA : 
this is my sql query :

```
 SELECT ID AS Identifier, IFNULL(INTITULE,'') AS NAME_INTITULE, 
IFNULL(ID_CAT,'') AS CODE_CATEGORIE
FROM db_1.evenement
 where DATE_HIST > (select IFNULL(max(date_record),'0000-00-00 00:00:00') 
                   from db_2.record_status where db_destination_name='AB' );
```

How to make it work with two dataset :

Dataset ds_evenement : contain the *evenement*  records

Dataset ds_record_status : contain the *record_status*  records

Comment: You need a variable and the StringBuilder class.

Answer (score 0):

You can select maximum date, cross join and filter:

```
// Select max value from ds_record_status
ds_record_status.select(
    coalesce(max(col("date_record")), lit(0).cast("timestamp")).alias("max_date")
).crossJoin(ds_evenement).where("DATE_HIST > max_date)
```

or just register both tables:

```
 ds_record_status.createOrReplaceTempView("ds_record_status");
 ds_evenement.createOrReplaceTempView("ds_evenement");
```

and use you query almost as-is:

- Replacing `IFNULL` with `coalesce`.
- Removing schema prefixes.

Comment: the both of tables have other columns who i dont need, the result well be registred into one table.

Comment: Thank you much appreciated your help.